# Add new lines to csv file from text files

Tags: python, csv, text

I have a dataset in .csv format. The dataset has 3 columns and 3500 lines like this:

```
        a   |             b           |   c  |
    -----------------------------------------
1       0   |            ..           |  **  |
2       1   |            ..           |  **  |
3       4   |            ..           |  **  |
4       3   |            ..           |  **  |
5       1   |            ..           |  **  |
6       2   |            ..           |  **  |
3000    .   |            ..           |  **  |
3499    .   |            ..           |  **  |
3500    .   |            ..           |  **  |
```

I have ***m*** folders with ***n*** text files. Each file name in these folders has specific expression. These expressions are like _AB / _CD / _EF / etc.

I want to add new lines to the .csv file :
For the first column (a) I want to add a number which depends on the expressions in files names (_AB, _CD etc.).

For example if the filename of the text file contains ***_AB*** then add the number 0 to the column (a), if it contains _CD then add 1 etc.

For the (b) column I want to add the content of that text file.

For example if my folder contains these text files:

```
Filename             |      Content
-----------------------------------------
Text_File_1_AB.txt   | 100 200 140 240 120 160
Text_File_2_AB.txt   | 170 180 190 100 110 120
Text_File_3_AB.txt   | 130 140 150 160 150 160
```

The .csv file will be like :

```
        a   |             b           |   c  |
    -----------------------------------------
1       0   |                         |      |
2       1   |                         |      |
3       4   |                         |      |
4       3   |                         |      |
5       1   |                         |      |
6       2   |                         |      |
3000    .   |                         |      |
3499    .   |                         |      |
3500    .   |                         |      |
3501    0   | 100 200 140 240 120 160 |      |
3502    0   | 170 180 190 100 110 120 |      |
3503    0   | 130 140 150 160 150 160 |      |
```

This code works, but I'm having the same line (of a certain text file content) in every new lines added. What's wrong?

```
import csv
import os

for i in range (1,517):
x = [f for f in os.listdir('/Folder_name/')]
with open('/Folder_name/'+f, 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()
    list1=[0,content,'Something']
    with open("file_name.csv", "a") as fp:
        wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
        wr.writerow(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly. (for those who need it)

```
import csv
import os

for file in os.listdir('/Folder_name/'):
    with open('/Folder_name/'+file, 'r') as content_file:
            content = content_file.read()
    list1=[0,content,'Something']
    with open("file_name.csv", "a") as fp:
        wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
        wr.writerow(list1)
```